# What is correct parameters for opus webm audio to seekable with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I tried to record `audio.webm` using HTML5 MediaRecorder on Chrome and it cannot seek. Which is a known bug for Chrome. And I'm using ffmpeg to fix this problem with billion different ways, but still haven't succeeded.

```
ffmpeg -i <source> -fflags +genpts output.webm
```

It works if the source file has a video stream, but it didn't work for only audio stream with opus encoding. When I try to seek, Chrome dev tools network timeline keep downloading the entire file:

[image: screenshot]

I even tried to play with VLC and still cannot seek. Then I tried to convert webm to MP3:

```
ffmpeg -i <source> output.mp3
```

Now I can seek in the browser and any other media players, but the output file's duration and start time is incorrect:

[image: output.web and output.mp3]

What is the correct ffmpeg parameters to fix this problem?

Comment: If we know what the Chrome bug is, that may give a clue as to how to work around it.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but I think framedata or metadata is missing or malformed on Chrome MediaRecorder.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: This is the [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012) link marked WontFix.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i <source> -c copy output.webm` and `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i <source> -c copy output.webm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been research about it and found an issue discussion from https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs. In the issue discussion they used a node module called `ts-ebml`. It's like:

```
ts-ebml -s not_seekable.webm | cat > seekable.webm
```

It fixed non-seekable webm metadata duration and cues.

I hope it will be help somebody.

Comment: Which issue discussion you are referring to? Where do you get `ts-ebml`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember and cannot find it now. It was a year ago.

Comment: I just found a reference https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/webm-wasm/issues/3

Comment: You can get it via npm: `npm i -g ts-ebml`